# get basepath and baseurl in cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I am developing a product(web application) in PHP.
I need to put it on online. I am using cpanel.

My probelm is:: My code snippet has the following:

```
$basepath = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd/";
$baseurl = "http://sys6003/abcd/";
```

I am unable to match this part to live part of cpanel.

cpanel Structure:

```
/home/account_name/public_html/www.abcd.com(folder)
```

I've tried too many but I didn't get it.
More over I am new to cpanel. Someone, Please Help me.

Comment: <?php
function GetBasePath() {
    return substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(strrchr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], "\\")));
}
?>

Comment: Thank you but it is returning "index.php" along with URL. I need only base path.

Comment: Remove inder.php using .htacces.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you describe how to do it?

Comment: do you have htaccess file ?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I have .htaccess file, With "GetBasePath()" function itself, I came to know that what is project base path. I copied that bath pasted in variable  $basepath. But it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

**BaseURL:** It is the URL where you will access the file from any computer on the Internet like `http://www.Mywebsite.com/Mydirectory/MyFile.html`

**BasePath:** It is the PATH to access files from your "inside" your "Server", it would look something like that `/htdocs/Mydirectory/MyFile.html`

The way for me to remember the difference between the 2 since I don't use it to often is to tell me: **URL is for browsers** (like Firefox, Chrome) and **PATH is for Applications** usually in PHP, JS or HTML usually. You **CAN'T** call the path from a browser ;-)